# Losing indefinite Spanish residency, but reobtaining it after returning years later

Tags: resident-permit, residency, spain, relocation

I'm a British citizen in possession of a British passport currently living in Spain and have been living here for 19 years. I have residencia here, an A4 piece of paper with my NIE with no expiry date (which I think is an indefinite permanent residency?)

From what I understand, I'd lose my residency if I left Spain to work in the UK and spent a year living there, however if I were to return in the future, would I still be able to get my residency back? I read somewhere that you can apply to "recover" it, so you don't have to meet the same requirements as someone requesting it for the first time

Comment: I thought you can get Spanish citizenship after ten years of residency and both Spain and the UK allows for dual citizenship.

Comment: @chx I was under the impression that Spain only allows for dual citizenship if you're from a country that has a close relationship to Spain, like Latin American countries that used to be under Spanish Rule? I don't think that's an option for me here

Comment: http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/en/ServiciosAlCiudadano/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Paginas/Nacionalidad.aspx "
Nationality by residence

This method of acquisition of nationality requires continued legal residence in Spain for ten years immediately prior to the application."

Comment: @chx But doing so means I am forced to surrender my British nationality right? That isn't an option for me as I'm about to move to the UK. I want to know about when I come back

Comment: I see nothing that would indicate that.

Comment: @chx [On wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_nationality_law) 
`Foreign nationals who acquire Spanish nationality must renounce their previous nationality, unless they are natural-born citizens of an Iberoamerican country, Andorra, the Philippines or Equatorial Guinea.`

Comment: Even after what happened to the Scots Wikipedia, people still believe one word of it?? What more do you need? It is no more relevant than what any rando tells you on in the pub! http://www.exteriores.gob.es/ this is the Spanish government.

Comment: @chx I just linked wikipedia as it was in English and was the closest at hand. The [Spanish government website](https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/es/ciudadanos/nacionalidad/que-es-nacionalidad/tener-doble-nacionalidad) says:
`No es necesario que renuncien a su nacionalidad quienes fueran naturales de países iberoamericanos, de Andorra, Filipinas, Guinea Ecuatorial o Portugal.`
which translates to:
`It is not necessary for those who are natives of Ibero-American countries, Andorra, the Philippines, Equatorial Guinea or Portugal to renounce their nationality.` which matches the wiki

Comment: If I were you I'd [change my NIE for a TIE](https://www.mptfp.gob.es/dam/es/portal/delegaciones_gobierno/delegaciones/catalunya/servicios/extranjeria/guia_tramites/Nota_web_Brexit.pdf.pdf) and then return (for a brief holiday) before 12 months have elapsed in order to reset the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to recover your residency back. Anyway, you could apply for Spanish citizenship.

Yes, I am aware than *Foreign nationals who acquire Spanish nationality must renounce their previous nationality*. But this "renounce" is only in the oath, you don't need to present any certificate or formalize this in any way later. So in reality, it doesn't have any effect.