# Taking Spanish citizenship while retaining British citizenship

Tags: citizenship, spain

Spain only allows [dual nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship) for nationals of a limited number of their ex colonies.

> Foreign nationals who acquire Spanish nationality must renounce their previous nationality

But if someone renounces their previous nationality, does anyone inform their previous nation of this?

What's to stop me from naturalising in Spain, saying that I renounce my British nationality, and then applying for a British passport afterwards?

Comment: Please search this site. I believe someone wrote that they gave their Britsh passport to the Spanish with an declaration of renunciation which was sent to the British authorities. The passport was simply sent back to the passport holder. Some countries require that a certificate of renunciation is to be presented before nationlisation takes place.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I searched before asking the question. The closest question I found was [this one](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/21866/17121) which asks about residency, not naturalisation. The answer there talks about naturalisation and says that: "this "renounce" is only in the oath, you don't need to present any certificate or formalize this in any way later. So in reality, it doesn't have any effect.". I can't find anything else.

Comment: According to [this site](https://costaluzlawyers.es/blog/can-you-be-british-and-spanish-at-the-same-time/) renouncing your British citizenship in Spain has no binding effect on the UK. For practical purposes in Spain you’d be considered Spanish, and in the UK, British. AFAIK unless you [apply to the UK](https://www.gov.uk/renounce-british-nationality) renouncing elsewhere has no effect.

Comment: @Traveller that's great, thank you!